# How do you do logical exclusive XOR in the C preprocessor with defines

Tags: c++, c, preprocessor

What's the simplest way to ensure that only one of two names is defined, for example:

```
#define USE_OPTION1
#define USE_OPTION2

#if not(USE_OPTION1 ^ USE_OPTION2)
#error "You must use at least one option, but not both"
#endif
```

I know there's no logical XOR in C or C++, so what's the best way of doing this? It doesn't have to be this, does it:

```
#define USE_OPTION1
#define USE_OPTION2
        
#ifdef USE_OPTION1
  #ifdef USE_OPTION2
  #error "You can't use both"
  #endif
#endif

#ifdef USE_OPTION2
  #ifdef USE_OPTION1
  #error "You can't use both"
  #endif
#endif

#ifndef USE_OPTION1
  #ifndef USE_OPTION2
  #error "You must use at least one"
  #endif
#endif
```

Comment: cand you use `!((USE_OPTION1) ^ (USE_OPTION2))?` or `!(USE_OPTION1) != !(USE_OPTION2)`?

Comment: @CEPB if it was `#define USE_OPTION1 true` than yes. but here it doesn't make sense for the preprocessor that you apply an operation on a define symbol. the syntax error here will be "expected an expression"

Answer (score 8, accepted):

you can solve this by checking if both are defined equally. so `0 0` and `1 1` will throw the error, while `0 1` and `1 0` are allowed.

```
#if defined(USE_OPTION1) == defined(USE_OPTION2)
#error "You must use at least one option, but not both"
#endif
```